# D3 - change y.domain to start at min amount

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/3gikXOR8EydIcA3wcBMb?p=preview

Its a simple bar chart.

The amounts in the bars is very small.

Current I'm using

```
y.domain([0, d3.max( data, (d) => d.finish)]);
```

To get the y.domain but this starts at 0 and the bars are very small.

I want the y axis to start just below the lowerst number but if I use

```
y.domain([d3.min( data, (d) => d.start), d3.max( data, (d) => d.finish)]);
```

It breaks the chart and I get errors that the height is a negtive value.

What am I doing wrong, how can I get y axis numers closer to the limits of the data and show the bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate height based on start and finish value

```
.attr("height", (d, i) => {
        return y(d.start) - y(d.finish);
      });
```